# Evaluate an expression in GDB and LLDB

Tags: gcc, gdb, lldb

I'm trying to understand GDB and LLDB so that I can efficiently used it to debug my programs at any point.

But it seems that I'm stuck: I'm not sure how to print the output of a C library function like `pow`, `strnlen` etc. If I ever want to explore their output.

Following are by LLDB and GDB outputs:

```
   3    int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
   4       int a = pow(3,2);
-> 5       printf("the value of a is %d",a);
   6       return 0;
   7    }
(lldb) print pow(3,1)
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
error: 'pow' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
(lldb) print strlen("abc")
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
error: 'strlen' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
(lldb) expr int a = strlen("abc");
error: 'strlen' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
(lldb) expr int a = strlen("abc");
```

GDB output:

```
Starting program: /Users/noobie/workspaces/myWork/pow 
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 35243]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)

Thread 2 hit Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbffb10) at pow.c:5
5      int a = pow(3,2);
(gdb) print pow(3,2)
No symbol "pow" in current context.
(gdb) set pow(3,2)
No symbol "pow" in current context.
(gdb) set pow(3,2);
No symbol "pow" in current context.
(gdb) print pow(3,2);
No symbol "pow" in current context.
(gdb) call pow(3,2)
No symbol "pow" in current context.
(gdb)
```

I have compiled the program using

> gcc -g3 pow.c -o pow

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error you are getting from lldb, e.g.:

```
error: 'strlen' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
```

is just what it says.  You need to cast the call to the proper return type:

```
(lldb) print (size_t) strlen("abc")
(size_t) $0 = 3
```

The reason the type information is missing from `strlen` and `printf` etc. is that to save space, the compiler only writes the signatures of functions into the debug information when it sees the definition of the function, not at every use site.  Since you don't have the debug information for the standard C libraries, you don't have this information.

The reason the debugger requires this information before it will call the function is that if you call a function that returns a structure, but generate code as though the function returned a scalar value, calling the function will corrupt the stack of the thread on which the function was called, ruining your debug session.  So lldb doesn't guess about this.

Note, on macOS, the system has "module maps" for most of the system libraries, which allow lldb to reconstruct types from the modules.  To tell lldb to load a module when debugging a pure C program, run this command:

```
(lldb) expr -l objective-c -- @import Darwin
```

If you are debugging an ObjC program, you can leave off the language specification.  After this expression runs, lldb will have loaded the module map and you can call most of the functions in the standard C libraries without casting.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at disassemble you'll see it just contains raw resulting value with no call to `pow` function. gcc knows what `pow` is and calculates it during compilation. There is no need to link with `libm` which contains implementation of given function => no function is present at runtime so debugger don't have anything to call.

You can force link via e.g. adding `-lm` (can be overridden with `--as-needed` linker flag, though).

Comment: Tried `gcc  -nodefaultlibs  -lm -g pow.c -o pow `  did not work

Comment: First, what "did not work" means exactly? Second, there is no way it will link - since you use `printf`, which is in `libc` (part of standard libs, and not specified explicitly). Third, why do you want `-nodefaultlibs` at all? Fourth, since debuging information don't have info for `pow` function (as it wasn't used), to match correct type you'll have to use somehting like `p ((double (*)(double, double))&pow)(3, 2)`.